# Android app crashes when camera opened

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

[image: logcat] [image: manifest] [image: code snippet 1] [image: code snippet 2] [image: code snippet 3] I still can't figure out what's causing my app to crash. I've already included permissions and user features but still wont work. How to solve this?

P.S. I'm new to Android.

Comment: show  your logcat

Comment: May be required permission is an issue. Without logs and code sample it will be hard to solve the issue.

Comment: HI! @AnisurRahmanTonu already posted the logcat.

Comment: I think when you run an App in your Device API above lollipop you have to give manually Permissions to that APP. Go to Settings>Installed Apps>Your_App>Permissions and then enable permission whichever you want to provide.

Comment: @kendi please share your error log

Comment: @kendi show the error or exception from logcat which crashes your app

Comment: Dear @kendi, here on StackOverflow, please post code and logs as text, whenever possible. Screenshots may be hard to read and analyze. If you have a very long text, consider uploading it to GitHub gist or other sharing site, and post a link in your question. In your question, only embed essential pieces of this text.

Comment: Take Permission of camera and read external storage. 
If you are running it below 23 then it will work. else you have to add run time permission which are required for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

From What I can see you did not get Permission from User. (Adding Camera Permission in Manifest is not enough)

In `onActivityResult` you have to get the image from `data` variable. e.g `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`

I recommend you have a look at this answer from @jengelsma, in how to `Capture Image from Camera`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5991757/2945356

> PS. If you change logcat filter to `ERROR`. It will show you exactly what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the cause of the problem is that your `takePictureIntent()` calls `startActivityForResult()` twice.

Also note that [`EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION) does not apply to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. PLease follow more closely the official Android [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskCaptureIntent).